# I can no longer modify my files! What happened?

Tags: vuejs3, memory-mapped-io

I was working on a vuejs project when all of a sudden some files become immutable. In the browser, they appear with a double marked (mapped).
I don't know what it is . So, what I can do to revert this behavior as I can no longer change my files.
I am of Fedora 38. I met this problem while trying different libraries of form validation. When I use the same project (copy) in windows 11 the trouble is the same.
Thank you for help

My **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "compta-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check \"build-only {@}\" --",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --build --force"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "element-plus": "^2.4.4",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vee-validate": "^4.12.3",
    "vue": "^3.3.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.19.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.0",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.17.2",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.26.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.10",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.25"
  }
}
```

**ts.config.app.json**

```
{
    "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
     "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
     "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
     "compilerOptions": {
          "composite": true,
          "noEmit": true,
          "baseUrl": ".",
          "types": ["node"],
              "paths": {
              "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

ts.config.json

```
{
"files": [],
"references": [
    {
        "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
        "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
],
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "types": ["element-plus/global"]
    }
}
```

ts.config.node.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "vite.config.*",
    "vitest.config.*",
    "cypress.config.*",
    "nightwatch.conf.*",
    "playwright.config.*"
  ],
 "compilerOptions": {
      "composite": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "module": "ESNext",
      "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
      "types": ["node"]
      }
}
```

**[image: what I see in the browser dev tool]**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[image]

Comment: What symptoms of your problem led you to this conclusion?

Comment: Thank you for you response. When I do a change on a file and check the app. The change is not applied. For example I submit a form, and in the submit function i only write console.ouput('something'). But what i see is what the submit function was supposed to do before the change e.g. console.output('other thing'). When in the browser I look to the code, i see 2 files one normal and the other with the same name followed by (mapped). In the file explorer of vscode, the file name is followed by a number 2. But the main symptom is that my changes are effect-less.

Comment: Ok this has nothing to do with memory-mapped files. Competely different concept. I would suggest you _edit_ your question, and rewrite it with this information and a lot more detail.

Comment: There may be something wrong with your build (share those settings), or if you use docker it may be a misconfiguration there too. (share if applicable)

Comment: I will try to do what you ask but it is not easy to describe something you don't understand. For info I don't use docker.

Comment: I started a new project this morning but it has also turned wrong with a lot of files markde mapped in the browser a immutable. See last image.